# Can i draw animation?

Tags: drawing

I learned from hadith you are not allowed to draw portraits. And hang them up. However what if you have drawings with eyes in a book?I don't draw realistic humans just anime or cartoons. Is it allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Today there are a number of Islamic illustrated books and animated cartoons on the market for children. Due to the prohibition of image making in Islamic Law, people have differing opinions about how to approach these media.

A breakdown of the ruling on pictures and figurines in accordance with the 4 preponderant schools of jurisprudence (Hanafi, Maliki, Shafi'i, Hanbali):

- Picture of something inanimate such as a solid object or plant.
  **Permissible amongst all 4 schools.**
- Picture of something animate such as a human or animal:

  - Incomplete form. **Permissible amongst all 4 schools**.
  - Complete form: Figurine/3D
- For the purpose of child entertainment/education. **Permissible amongst
  all 4 schools.**
- Not for the purpose of child entertainment/education. **Impermissible
  amongst all 4 schools**

  - Sketch/2D
- Venerated. **Impermissible according to the vast majority and disliked
  within the Maliki school.**
- Not venerated. **Permissible amongst all 4 schools.**

There are also many more opinions found about animation which you can find [here.](http://en.islamtoday.net/artshow-383-3367.htm)

1. [Reference 1](http://en.islamtoday.net/artshow-383-3367.htm)
2. [Reference 2](https://www.quora.com/Is-portrait-drawing-forbidden-in-Islam)

If you can further questions, see [here](http://www.shiachat.com/forum/topic/235004608-lawsdrawing-people-is-haram/).

Comment: Hope, it helps.